# How to change two variables at the same time in flutter?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter

#### Goal:

I am trying to create list of items which have a counter to decrement or increase, and at the same time a total is shown with the final price.

#### Problem:

The problem is that both variables cannot be changed at the same time because they are a `setState` and I don't know how to do it asynchronously.

I also don't know how to convert this class to a widget that can be called normal to build the list.

```
class FlutterExample extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
     body: new ListView(
       children: new List.generate(5, (i)=>new ListTileItem(
         title: "Item#$i",
       )),
     ),
   );
 }
 
}
class ListTileItem extends StatefulWidget {
final  String title;
 ListTileItem({this.title});
 @override
 _ListTileItemState createState() => new _ListTileItemState();
}

class _ListTileItemState extends State<ListTileItem> {
 int _itemCount = 0;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Container(
   
     child: new Row(
       children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.remove),onPressed: ()=>setState(()=>_itemCount--),),
           new Text(_itemCount.toString()),
           new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.add),onPressed: ()=>setState(()=>_itemCount++))
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: why put async in Iconbutton directly? if your goal is to have a delay do it inside your deleteAditionalOrder(),
remove async in your icon button and It is good to go

Comment: Yes, I already changed the errors I had, and the error I have is that I don't know how to convert this class as a widget, since every time I change the state of the variable the class is redrawn and the value is reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Darish says, the `Widget` which holding the state is supposed to be the Parent, in this case `Flutter Example`. It needs to provide `ListTileItem` with functions that change the state of the variables.

I made a quick change with your code. You can try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/ef85a80eb5acd21d9b9b8f034baf5e24)

**Snippet:**

```
class FlutterExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlutterExampleState createState() => _FlutterExampleState();
}

class _FlutterExampleState extends State<FlutterExample> {
  int total = 0;
  List<int> individualCount = [];
  List<String> individualTitle = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    List.generate(5, (i) {
      individualCount.add(0);
      individualTitle.add('item ${i + 1}');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void increment(int index) {
    setState(() {
      individualCount[index]++;
      total++;
    });
  }

  void decrement(int index) {
    setState(() {
      individualCount[index]--;
      total--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 120,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('total: $total', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
          SizedBox(height: 24),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: individualCount.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTileItem(
                  title: individualTitle[index],
                  count: individualCount[index],
                  decrement: () => decrement(index),
                  increment: () => increment(index),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListTileItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final int count;
  final Function decrement;
  final Function increment;

  ListTileItem({this.title, this.count, this.decrement, this.increment});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('$title'),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: decrement,
            ),
            Text('$count'),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: increment,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks is just what I needed but I have an error that comes out::A RenderFlex overflowed by 199629 pixels on the right. Icons Button require a material widget

Comment: You can remove the width: 120 of the Container or even remove the Container itself

Answer (score 0):

Keep the state in the upper widget and pass it down the tree so that child widget can always redraw it correctly.

What you need is a StateManagement setup in your project. Read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) article for more details.